# Javers comparing lists with different order

Tags: java, list, compare, javers

I have two list with same data but in different orders.

Why is that Javers `compareCollections` method see two changes (one ValueRemoved and one ValueAdded) with Levenshtein distance?

Maybe Javers doesn't allow multiple fields with `@Id` annotation?

**Code:**

```
class A {
    @Id
    private String a;
    @Id
    private String b;

    public A() {
    }

    public A(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Test
public void testJavers() {
    List<A> oldList = Arrays.asList(
            new A("a1", "b1"),
            new A("a2", "b2"));
    List<A> newList = Arrays.asList(
            new A("a2", "b2"),
            new A("a1", "b1"));
    Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers()
         .withListCompareAlgorithm(ListCompareAlgorithm.LEVENSHTEIN_DISTANCE)
         .build();
    Diff diff = javers.compareCollections(oldList, newList, A.class);
    System.out.println(javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(diff));
}
```

**Result:**

```
{
  "changes": [
    {
      "changeType": "ListChange",
      "globalId": {
        "valueObject": "org.javers.core.graph.LiveGraphFactory$ListWrapper"
      },
      "property": "list",
      "elementChanges": [
        {
          "elementChangeType": "ValueRemoved",
          "index": 1,
          "value": {
            "a": "a2",
            "b": "b2"
          }
        },
        {
          "elementChangeType": "ValueAdded",
          "index": 0,
          "value": {
            "a": "a2",
            "b": "b2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you trace into the Javers code to see what it does?

Comment: No, I've not seen the Javers source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to choose exactly one property as the Id-property. If you have two properties with @Id, JaVers picks one of them as the Id-property (which one is undefined).

Second, both algorithms for comparing lists (`LEVENSHTEIN` and `SIMPLE`) pay attention to ordering. Lists are ordered collections. If you don't care about ordering use Sets.

Comment: Old post... But what if I don't care about ordering, and I do care about duplicates?

Comment: then you need bags, but currently bags aren't supported in javers